# Using Converters while reading a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am trying to read a csv file into a pyspark dataframe. I wanted to convert a particular string filed to an integer based on a simple logic.

While reading with pandas this can be done simply with converters

In pandas it can be done like this if status is 'acquired' will be converted to 1 else 0

```
  dataset=pd.read_csv("../input/startup-success-prediction/startup data.csv",\
       converters={'status': lambda x: int(x == 'acquired')})
```

how to do this while reading a pyspark dataframe.

```
   df=spark.read.csv("../input/startup-success-prediction/startup data.csv")
```

i wanted to add the same type of converter in pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Spark API does not offer that capability in the `spark.read.csv` function (current options for CSV read/write can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html)), the column conversion can be performed after you read in the data using the `when` function with `otherwise`:

```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import when
   df = spark.read.csv("../input/startup-success-prediction/startup data.csv")
   df = df.withColumn('status', when(df['status'] == 'acquired', True).otherwise(False))
```

Documentation for the `when` function can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html).